# Pandas excel difference generator

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to create a python program that gives me the differences between 2 big excel files with multiple sheets. I got it to print the results to an excel, but apparently when one of the cells contains datetime data then the operation of multiplying a boolean dataframe with the dataframe that contains dates doesn't work anymore. I get the following error :

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'bool' and 'datetime.datetime'

'EDIT' : I just realized this method doesn't work for strings neither (It only works for pure numerical data). What would be a better way to do this, that works on strings, numbers and time data?

```
#start of program
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import ExcelWriter
    import numpy as np

    df1 = pd.read_excel('4_Input EfE_2030.xlsm',None)
    df2 = pd.read_excel('5_Input EfE_2030.xlsm',None)
    keys1=df1.keys()
    keys2=df2.keys()
    writer = ExcelWriter('test1.xlsx')
#loop for all sheets and create new dataframes with the differences    
    for x in keys1:
        df3 = pd.read_excel('4_Input EfE_2030.xlsm',sheetname=x,header=None)
        df4 = pd.read_excel('5_Input EfE_2030.xlsm',sheetname=x,header=None)
        dif = df3 != df4
        df=dif*df3
        df2=dif*df4
        nrcolumns=len(df.columns)
#when there are no differences in the entire sheet the dataframe will be empty. Add 1 to row indexes so the number coincides with excel rownumbers
        if not df.empty:
            # df.columns = ['A']
            df.index = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
        if not df2.empty:
            # df2.columns = ['A']
            df2.index = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
#delete rows with all 0
        df = df.loc[~(df == 0).all(axis=1)]
        df2 = df2.loc[~(df2 == 0).all(axis=1)]
#create new df with the data of the 2 sheets
        result = pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1)
        print(result)
        result.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=x)
```

Comment: I updated my answer to describe a new approach given the edits to your original question (i.e,. only strictly numeric values work for your approach). I hope it's helpful. It gets you some of the way there but not all of the way. I just ran out of time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated answer

#### Approach

This is an interesting question. Another approach is to compare the column values in one Excel worksheet against the column values in another Excel worksheet by using the `Panel` data structure offered by Pandas. This data structure stores data as a 3-dimensional array. With the data from two Excel worksheets stored in a `Panel` we can then compare rows across worksheets that are uniquely identified by one or a combination of columns (e.g, a unique ID). to make this comparison by applying a custom function that compares the value in each cell of each column in one worksheet to the value in the same cell of the same column in the second worksheet. One benefit of this approach is that the datatype of each value no longer matters since we're just comparing values (e.g., `1 == 1`, `'my name' == 'my name'`, etc.).

#### Assumptions

This approach makes several assumptions about your data:

1. The rows in each of the worksheets share one or a combination of columns that uniquely identify each row.
2. The columns of interest for comparison exist in both worksheets and share the same column headers.

(There may be other assumptions I'm failing to notice.)

#### Implementation

The implementation of this approach is a bit involved. Also, because I do not have access to your data, I cannot customize the implementation specifically to your data. With that said, I'll implement this approach using some dummy data shown below.

**"Old" dataset:**

```
id  col_num col_str                col_datetime
 1  123     My string 1            2001-12-04
 2  234     My string 2            2001-12-05
 3  345     My string 3            2001-12-06
```

**"New" dataset:**

```
id  col_num col_str                col_datetime
 1  123     My string 1 MODIFIED   2001-12-04
 3  789     My string 3            2001-12-10
 4  456     My string 4            2001-12-07
```

Notice the following differences about these two dataframes:

1. `col_str` in the row with `id` 1 is different
2. `col_num` in the row with `id` 3 is different
3. `col_datetime` in the row with `id` 3 is different
4. The row with `id` 2 exists in "old" but not "new"
5. The row with `id` 4 exists in "new" but not "old"

Okay, let's get started. First, we read in the datasets into separate dataframes:

```
df_old = pd.read_excel('old.xlsx', 'Sheet1', na_values=['NA'])
df_new = pd.read_excel('new.xlsx', 'Sheet1', na_values=['NA'])
```

Then we add a new version column to each dataframe to keep our thinking straight. We'll also use this column later to separate out rows from the "old" and "new" dataframes into their own separate dataframes:

```
df_old['VER'] = 'OLD'
df_new['VER'] = 'NEW'
```

Then we concatenate the "old" and "new" datasets into a single dataframe. Notice that the `ignore_index` parameter is set to `True` so that we ignore the index as it is not meaningful for this operation:

`df_full = pd.concat([df_old, df_new], ignore_index=True)`

Now we're going to identify all of the duplicate rows that exist across the two dataframes. These are rows where all of the column values are the same across the "old" and "new" dataframes. In other words, these are rows where no differences exist:

Once identified, we drop these duplicates rows. What we're left with are the rows that (a) are different between the two dataframes, (b) exist in the "old" dataframe but not the "new" dataframe, and (c) exist in the "new" dataframe but not the "old" dataframe:

`df_diff = df_full.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'col_num', 'col_str', 'col_datetime'])`

Next we identify and extract the values for `id` (i.e., the primary key across the "old" and "new" dataframes) for the rows that exist in both the "old" and "new" dataframes. It's important to note that these `id`s **do not** include rows that exist in one or the other dataframes but not both (i.e., rows removed or rows added):

`diff_ids = df_diff.set_index('id').index.get_duplicates()`

Now we restrict `df_full` to only those rows identified by the `id`s in `diff_ids`:

`df_diff_ids = df_full[df_full['id'].isin(diff_ids)]`

Now we move the duplicate rows from the "old" and "new" dataframes into separate dataframes that we can plug into a `Panel` data structure for comparison:

```
df_diff_old = df_diff_ids[df_diff_ids['VER'] == 'OLD']
df_diff_new = df_diff_ids[df_diff_ids['VER'] == 'NEW']
```

Next we set the index for both of these dataframes to the primary key (i.e., `id`). This is necessary for `Panel` to work effectively:

```
df_diff_old.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df_diff_new.set_index('id', inplace=True)
```

We slot both of these dataframes into a `Panel` data structure:

`df_panel = pd.Panel(dict(df1=df_diff_old, df2=df_diff_new))`

Finally we make our comparison using a custom function (`find_diff`) and the `apply` method:

```
def find_diff(x):
    return x[0] if x[0] == x[1] else '{} -> {}'.format(*x)

df_diff = df_panel.apply(find_diff, axis=0)
```

If you print out the contents of `df_diff` you can easily note the which values changed between the "old" and "new" dataframes:

```
    col_num     col_str                             col_datetime
id              
1   123         My string 1 -> My string 1 MODIFIED 2001-12-04 00:00:00 
3   345 -> 789  My string 3                         2001-12-06 00:00:00 -> 2001-12-10 00:00:00
```

#### Improvements

There are a few improvements I'll leave to you to make to this implementation.

1. Add a binary (1/0) flag that indicates if a one or more values in a
   row changed
2. Identify which rows in the "old" dataframe were removed
   (i.e., are not present in the "new" dataframe)
3. Identify which rows in the
   "new" dataframe were added (i.e., not present in the "old" dataframe)

### Original answer

#### Issue:

The issue is that you cannot perform arithmetic operations on `datetimes`.

However, you can perform arithmetic operations on `timedeltas`.

I can think of a few solutions that might help you:

#### Solution 1:

**Convert your `datetimes` to strings.**

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you're comparing Excel worksheets for differences, correct? If this is the case, then I don't think it matters if the `datetimes` are represented as explicit `datetimes` (i.e., you're not performing any `datetime` calculations).

To implement this solution you would modify your `pd.read_excel()' calls and explicitly set the`dtypes`parameter to convert your`datetimes` to strings:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('4_Input EfE_2030.xlsm', dtypes={'LABEL FOR DATETIME COL 1': str})
```

#### Solution 2:

**Convert your `datetimes` to `timedeltas`.**

For each `datetime` column, you can use: `pd.Timedelta(df['LABEL FOR DATETIME COL'])`

Overall, without seeing your data, I believe Solution 1 is the most straightforward.